# How do I make my wifi connection work with Linux mint 18?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, drivers

I just installed Linux Mint 18 kde version.All seemed to work fine except the wifi.There were wifi networks but laptop was not able to detect any connection.I checked that I am using BCM4313 wireless adapter provided by broadcom which is  shown as not working always in Linux [wireless site](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211/)

How can I make Linux mint 18 connect to WiFi?I had used Kubuntu 16.1 and Linux mint 17.3 before on my laptop and both seemed to work properly with WiFi devices.Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

To get the wifi working using the BCM4313 wifi card you can use the open-source driver `brcmsmac` :

```
sudo rmmod bcma
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Because the driver [is not fully supported](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211) you can switch to the [Proprietary driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Broadcom_STA_Wireless_driver_.28Proprietary.29) : *broadcom sta wireless driver*

> Please note: at least BCM4313 is not fully supported. Some models appears to work (users reported success), but some don't.

The [`bcmwl`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl) can be installed as follows :

Install the appropriate `linux-headers` package then run:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Unload the conflicting driver or create a blacklist file

```
sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

load the `wl` module

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: I tried that but going into driver manager I found that the device is already using bcmwl kernel source recommended driver.But still wifi connections are not shown

Comment: Remove the re-install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package from the terminal

Comment: I did that but "modprobe wl "command still shows module wl not found.

Comment: run `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: I tried that too....

Comment: I tried that ....The output was: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic

Comment: install the `broadcom-sta-dkms` package then reload the `wl` module

Comment: I installed the broadcom-sta-dkms package then did sudo modprobe wl...But the ouput was same as before

Comment: did you have an error when runing `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: more info here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Broadcom_STA_Wireless_driver_.28Proprietary.29

Comment: Yes it shows an error: modprobe: ERROR:../libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/modules.dep.bin'
Modprobe:FATAL: module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic

Comment: Run `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.8.0-46-generic`

Comment: Also Turn off the secure boot from your bios setting , the secure boot prevent unsigned module to be loaded